# for loop in a column

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a column named STOREIdentifier in a dataframe which has data for 9 stores. I want to count the units sold by these stores using a for loop. Basically, I'm calculating market share for each store. The units column has data for units sold.

```
for(i in unique(consumerData$STOREIdentifier)){
    salesPerStore[i] = aggregate(consumerData$units,by=list(consumerData$STOREIdentifier[i]),sum)
    salesPerStore
    totalSales = sum(consumerData$units)
    totalSales
    Print("Market share for store",i)
    marketshare[i] = salesPerStore[i]/totalSales
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data and the desired result

Comment: units dollars weekNum STOREIdentifier panelistNumber FLAVORID pricePerUnit
1 2 2.18 1 6 1 415 1.09
2 1 1.09 1 6 1 488 1.09
3 1 0.98 2 6 1 399 0.98
4 1 1.09 2 6 1 420 1.09
5 1 1.29 2 5 1 467 1.29
6 1 1.09 2 6 1 507 1.09
7 2 2.18 5 7 1 415 1.09
8 1 1.09 5 7 1 525 1.09
9 1 1.09 12 6 1 488 1.09
10 2 2.18 12 5 1 520 1.09
11 1 0.75 65 6 1 488 0.75

Comment: for every store I want to calculate market share = number of units by each store/total number of units

Comment: Please edit the question and add the data and comments into the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
 ag <- aggregate(consumerData$units,by=list(consumerData$STOREIdentifier),FUN=sum)
 ag / sum(consumerData$units)
```

Comment: Could you also explain your solution?

Comment: basically, I have 9 different stores in STOREIdentifier column and I want to calculate the market share of each store. for calculating the market share my formula is = number of units by each store/total number of units . Your code is working but the o/p is in below form

Comment: Group.1            x
1 1.974591e-06 3.350881e-03
2 3.949182e-06 2.642891e-01
3 5.923773e-06 7.108527e-05
4 7.898364e-06 3.326198e-02
5 9.872955e-06 3.897171e-01
6 1.184755e-05 6.350087e-02
7 1.382214e-05 2.293823e-01
8 1.579673e-05 8.806676e-04
9 1.777132e-05 1.554595e-02 Instead I want to display market share of each store with store identifier I dont want group1 and x. Just STOREIdentifier column and corresponding market share